# Ember-data keeps saying "no mdel was found for"

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, requirejs, ember-data

I am trying to write a EMberjs application, using Ember-Data. also, require.js and coffeescript. despite following each and every guide and discussion I could find, i am still getting 'no model was found for' error.

here are my classes:

main.coffee (entry point for require.js):

```
require.config
  paths:
    jQuery:     "../javascript/jquery-2.1.1.min"
    handlebars: "../javascript/handlebars-v1.3.0"
    ember:      "../javascript/ember.prod"
    ember_data: "../javascript/ember-data.prod",
  shim:
    ember:
         deps: ["jQuery", "handlebars"]
         exports: "Ember"
    'ember_data':
      deps:[ 'ember'],
      exports:'DS'

require ["app", "router"], (app, Router) ->
  app.deferReadiness()
  Router()
  app.advanceReadiness()
  return
```

app.coffee:

```
define "app", ["ember", "ember_data"], (Ember) ->
  window.app = Ember.Application.create()
  app.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend()
  app
```

router.coffee:

```
define "router", ["app", "ember-data", "ember", "models/person"], (app) ->
  ->         
    app.Router.map -> 
      @route 'home', path: "/"
      @resource('person', { path: 'person'},  ->
        @route('details', { path: ':slug' })
        return
      )
      return
    app.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend 
      model: ->

    app.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend 
      model: () ->
        return @store.find("Person")
```

models/person.coffee:

```
class app.Person extends DS.model
  first: DS.attr("string") 

app.Person.FIXTURES = { person: [
       {
        id: 1, 
        first: "first_1"
       },
       {
        id: 2, 
        first: "first_2"
       }
  ]}
```

but when i go to `http://localhost:9000/#/person,` i get this:

```
Error while processing route: person.index" "No model was found for 'Person'" "EmberError@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:13949:17
Store<.modelFor@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember-data.prod.js:11264:1
Store<.findAll@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember-data.prod.js:10845:20
Store<.find@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember-data.prod.js:10476:1
app.PersonRoute<.model@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/router.js:24:16
apply@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:19296:1
superWrapper@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:18867:15
Route<.deserialize@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:24467:16
applyHook@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:45215:16
HandlerInfo.prototype.runSharedModelHook@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:43237:22
UnresolvedHandlerInfoByParam<.getModel@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:43463:16
bind/<@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:45089:16
tryCatch@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:45538:16
invokeCallback@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:45550:17
publish@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:45521:11
@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:28956:9
DeferredActionQueues.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:679:11
DeferredActionQueues.prototype.flush@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:749:15
Backburner.prototype.end@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:135:11
createAutorun/backburner._autorun<@http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/ember.prod.js:521:9
" ember.prod.js:15069
```

any idea anyone?

EDIT:
it seems like if I move the person.coffee file from /models to the same level as main and App, and change the 'define' line in the router accordingly, it works as expected. Still a mystery to me :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but the problem might be in wrong formatted fixtures for App.Person.

Could you rewrite fixtures like this?

```
app.Person.FIXTURES = [
   {
    id: 1, 
    first: "first_1"
   },
   {
    id: 2, 
    first: "first_2"
   }
]
```

Comment: yup, tried that. in fact, i started like that, and changed after i saw a few debates saying it needs it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be defining your fixtures using reopenClass, so along these lines:

```
App.Documenter.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    { id: 1, firstName: 'Trek', lastName: 'Glowacki' },
    { id: 2, firstName: 'Tom' , lastName: 'Dale'     }
  ]
});
```

as seen in the example here http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-fixture-adapter/

The approach you're using is out of date.

Comment: Even if so (and I took it from the demo on 'getting started' on the main Ember page), making this change did not resolve it. still the same error

Comment: Can you put together a jsbin that produces the error?

Comment: shame to admit, but i am new to JSbin, and i'm having a hard time getting my multi-file, require.js coffeescript files to run. i keep getting unexplained errors.